# Pearson Correlation with Haskell Float Type Conflict

Tags: algorithm, haskell, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a program that loads 2 text files, converts the numbers in those files into 2 lists, and then calculates the pearson correletion between those lists.

The pearson function can only take floats, so I made a function called floatconvert to try to fix this problem, but it hasn't. I get an error saying "Couldn't match expected type 'IO b0' with actual type 'Float.' In the first argument of 'pearson', namely 'input1.'"

Any help with fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
main = do
    input1file <- readFile "input1.txt"
    input2file <- readFile "input2.txt"

    let input1 = floatconvert input1file
    let input2 = floatconvert input2file

    pearson input1 input2

floatconvert x = [ read a::Float | a <- words x ]

pearson xs ys = (psum-(sumX*sumY/n))/(sqrt((sumXsq-(sumX**2/n)) * (sumYsq-(sumY**2/n))))
    where
        n = fromIntegral (length xs)
        sumX = sum xs
        sumY = sum ys
        sumXsq = sum([ valX*valX | valX <- xs ])
        sumYsq = sum([ valY*valY | valY <- ys ])
        psum = sum([ fst val * snd val | val <- zip xs ys ])
```

Comment: Add type signatures to your functions, and the error message will get nearer to where the mistake is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is somewhat misleading in this case. The real problem is that `pearson` does not return `IO something`. If you meant to print the result, write

```
main = do
    ...    
    print $ pearson input1 input2
```

The reason for GHC's confusion here is that the inferred type of pearson is

```
pearson :: Floating a => [a] -> [a] -> a
```

so when you try to use it as a statement in the do-block, it infers from the return type that `a ~ IO b` and therefore the arguments must have type `[IO b]`. However, it already knows that they have type `[Float]` so you get a confusing error message about it being unable to match `Float` with `IO b` in the argument when the source of the problem is the return type.

I second Dave's advice about adding type signatures to your functions. It can make error messages more helpful. For example, if you had given `pearson` the type signature `pearson :: [Float] -> [Float] -> Float`, you would have gotten this message:

```
Pearson.hs:8:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `Float'
    In the return type of a call of `pearson'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: pearson input1 input2
```